# Android studio file tab is missing

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio file tab is missing, as you can see from the below screenshot. It's inconvenient to switch frequently between files without it. How can I bring it back?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You control it from the menu: Window -> Editor Tabs -> Tabs Placement[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should do your settings like :
[image]